# ToolStripMenuItem get enabled staying disables when change focus from one to other child form

Tags: vb.net, focus, mdichild, mdiparent, toolstripmenu

I've got some ToolStripMenuItem in a MDIParentForm, which I use to enable or disable depending of the status of the form I call clicking on them. If the form is enabled, the ToolStripMenuItem is disabled not allowing to open a new form like it's previously opened.
The fact it's that I don't know why, but when I change the focus from one child form to another, the ToolStripMenuItem wich was disabled, become enabled again (and it shouldn't, because I haven't set it like that by code).
I've have solved it using this:

```
Dim formPrevio As Form = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of AltaUsuario).Where(Function(frm) frm.Name = "AltaUsuario").SingleOrDefault
If formPrevio Is Nothing Then
   'open it again
Else
    'Get the focus again
End If
```

But I'd like to know if there's any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling a public function in the MDI Parent from the child form to disable the ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: I solved it with the code I wrote. What I wanted to know if is there any easy way to do this (managed by the own app). Any way thanks for your help.